# Set guest account to have no password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, user-accounts

How can I change the Guest account to have no password?
It seems that that may be causing some of my other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start Orb>Search box>type: netplwiz [enter]
Click on Continue (or supply an administrator's password) when prompted by UAC

Click "reset password"
Then click "OK"

Comment: the full article by Microsoft Answers [Remove Guest Password?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/remove-guest-password/6f746cbc-0136-4025-853a-5f2dd348e04c)

Answer (score 1):

Best practice normally has the Guest account disabled.  Enabling without password would open a  bit of a security hole as it is a known account and any attacker would likely try the account without passowrd.

Can you expain the issue so users might be able to offer more assistance?

Comment: Yes. It seems that it might be related to not being able to turn off password protected sharing. I have a bounty on the question with my sharing issues [here](http://superuser.com/questions/299864/homegroup-sharing-problems).